# Coinbase transaction data

Tags: coinbase-transaction

Can a coinbase transaction contain only data: 03 - length and 030303 - coinbase itself, or should the coinbase itself contain the height of the block?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki

> Add height as the first item in the coinbase transaction's scriptSig, and increase block version to 2. The format of the height is "serialized CScript" -- first byte is number of bytes in the number (will be 0x03 on main net for the next 150 or so years with 223-1 blocks), following bytes are little-endian representation of the number (including a sign bit). Height is the height of the mined block in the block chain, where the genesis block is height zero (0).

Comment: in this case, what should the part of the coinbase transaction look like now? example block 511824: ffffffff INDEX
55 LENGTH_COINBASE
03**50cf07**41d6a6ae79d8f62841d6a6ae79d8dba22f4254432e544f502ffabe6d6da64c1ef0a6cd6ffdecd9966246e336b366c8ba6ef07e9122485bb61b992bf61a8000000000000000fa00b68d1b3d000000000000 COINBASE (scriptsig)
ffffffff SEQUENCE,
where height block?

Comment: O, yes, i understund: 03 - ??? what is???                                                  
           50cf07(hex little endian) == 511824(dec)

Comment: okay, i'm little stupid)  **03** - length height block and **50cf07** is height block, after **0350cf07** next may come the any text in the range of 100 bytes? what is the encoding that will be deciphered on the sites as a coinbase? I want to write there **vbujym**